# How do I say what I mean for this closure-related code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

My first pass at this is an example of code in JavaScript that looks like it should work, but on closer inspection has different behavior. My Swift code presently has, with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON):

```
    for(var index = 0; index < datesToLoad.count; index += 1) {
        var formattedDate = formatter.stringFromDate(datesToLoad[index]);
        if (presentLocation["days"][formattedDate] == nil) {
            loadDataFromURL(NSURL:"http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?formatted=0&lat=\(presentLocation.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(presentLocation.coordinate.longitude)&date=\(formattedDate)&formatted=0", completion: {(data, error) -> Void in {
                if (var json = JSON(data:data)) {
                    presentLocation["days"][formattedDate]["sunrise"] = parser(json["results"]["sunrise"]);
                    presentLocation["days"][formattedDate]["sunset"] = parser(json["results"]["sunset"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now what I would expect is for the code not to work as intended. What I want to accomplish is that for each of the formattedDate values for the list, an asynchronous call to retrieve data from a URL is made, and each API call will work with the `formattedDate` value that was alive when the `loadDataFromURL()` call was made. What I expect will happen is that the loop will run quickly, spawning a few asynchronous requests, and `formattedDate` will be available with the last value it was defined. I can probably work around not knowing how to do this properly in Swift, as the data returned from API gives multiple timestamps, but I'd like to know the preferred way to go through multiple values for `formattedDate` with the callback function seeing the version that was active when its `loadDataFromURL()` function was called.

I could also get the results I want from completely unrolling the (four element) loop and using separate variable names for each closure-based API call, but I'd really prefer to know what is the right way to deal with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pass through the `for` loop creates a new `formattedDate` variable which is independent of the `formattedDate` variable created on any other pass.

Thus your loop should do what you intended.

Playground demo:

```
import XCPlayground
import UIKit

var blocks: [()->Void] = []

for i in 0..<5 {
    var s = "\(i)"
    blocks.append( { print(s) } )
}

print("calling blocks")

for block in blocks {
    block()
}
```

Output:

```
calling blocks
0
1
2
3
4
```